# How to connect to vagrant mysql database with Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, vagrant, sequelpro, scotchbox

How do I connect to vagrant mysql database with Sequel Pro? Specifically, ScotchBox 3?

Answer (score 3):

An easy option is to connect via Sequel Pro's SSH option:

MySQL Host: 192.168.33.10 (or your vagrant IP address, if different)

Username: root (or your custom mysql username)

Password: root (or your custom mysql password)

SSH Host: 192.168.33.10 (or your vagrant IP address, if different)

SSH User: vagrant

SSH Password: vagrant